# is it good to cache dom in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
    var $dom = $('#dom');
    $('#ddom').on('click', function(){
        $(this).text($dom.val());
    });
});
```

only get one dom once , use it everyWhere,
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/springLoo/9z7q0hae/)

Comment: What do you mean by **dom** here? the document or some element? Yes caching is good if you are dealing with large size DOM _(document object model)_...!

Comment: Yes, to avoid calling `jQuery()` at each occurrence in `.ready()` handler where `#dom` element is used

Comment: you are right but in my question , i should have mentioned that i use the dom cashe in the callbacks , so the momery can't be recycle by js engine.if i do like this , how will it influence the performance, will memory leak?and dom in js will connect with the document all the time.